# How to properly instantiate new PhpRenderer object

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm writing a custom renderer and following [this](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.renderer.php-renderer.html) tutorial that explains how to instantiate `PhpRenderer` object.

```
class CustomRenderer implements RendererInterface
{
    .....

    public function render( $nameOrModel, $values = null )
    {

        .....

        $renderer = new \Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer();
        $renderer->setResolver( $this->resolver );  // $this->resolver Zend\View\Resolver\AggregateResolver

        return $renderer->render( $model );  // $model Zend\View\Model\ViewModel

        .....
```

Renderer is constantly throwing errors like

> 'Zend\View\HelperPluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an
>   instance for translate

or

> 'No base path provided' in Zend\View\Helper\BasePath

etc. Basically everything that has to do with helpers in template does not work. Also, tried this code in controller, or with clean model but no luck. Resolver and model are correct.

How to properly instantiate new PhpRenderer object.

Comment: you didn't inject helper plugin manager, so new unconfigured is created as fallback instead.

Comment: @Xerkus, thanks, your comment led me to solution. Instead of creating a new renderer, I inject the existing one in renderer factory from the service manager.